# How can two threads share memory declared as variables in an object?

Tags: operating-system, computer-science

C programs can use global variables to share memory between functions executed in a parent and a child thread, but a Java program with several classes of objects doesn’t have such global variables.  How can two threads share memory declared as variables in an object?

Comment: They both need to access the same object reference, just like a pair of methods.  Done;)

Comment: 'C programs can use global variables to share memory between functions executed in a parent and a child thread,' yes, they can.  They can also share more.  A lot more.  In fact, they can share everything in the process, (OK, not always safely:).

Answer (score 0):

The practicable answer to this depends up on the language in which you are working.

In the theoretical, a process is an address space having one or more threads. A thread is a stream of execution having a process address space.

Because all the threads in the process share the same address space they can access each other's variables with no restrictions (for good or bad). Absolutely everything is shared.

Some programming languages, such as Ada have wonderful support for threads (tasks in Ada). Java has minimal support for threads. Classic C and C++ have no language support at all.

In a language like Ada, with real thread support, there are protected mechanisms for exchanging data among tasks. (But your Ada task could call an assembly language routine that can circumvent all that protection.) In C/C++ you create a task train wreck unless you explicitly plan to avoid one.

In Java, you can use static members (including static member functions) simulate a global variable that you can unsafely access.